# Trouble mounting a FAT32 IDE drive with USB adapter

Tags: disk, fat32

I have one of those 40 pin IDE to USB adapters. I can use this and mount an ext4 drive, but an older FAT32 drive will not mount.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /targetdirectory
```

gives me:
`mount: /media/.../...: can't read superblock on /dev/sdb.`

```
sudo parted -l /dev/sdb

Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Model: Initio MK2326FC (scsi)                                             
Disk /dev/sdb: 2199GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags
```

Do I need some kind of FAT32 driver or something?

`gparted` does not pick up the drive.
and  I am vague on what I did, but using an IDE to SATA adapter which did pick it up, doing a `dd if=` style backup attempt. It went on and on thinking the drive was 2000Gb as per the above results did not complete (or I gave up).

All part of a project to get a 486 with 128mb of RAM to run Linux (someone else has done it) and, more  urgently, to get a backup of these old FAT32 disks before they go kaput. (Clonezilla does not work with IDE/SATA adapters either).

Comment: being able to mount and use the ext4 IDE drive means that the 40 pins is all that is needed, so it is not, at least for the newer 40Gb drive, a problem of getting external power to the unused 4 pins (power)

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; but you do show you attempting to mount a device and not partition. The standard used by PCs using microsoft or IBM systems (DOS, OS/2 & windows) was to have a partition table & thus partitions which contained the file-system, not drive & file-system only (no partition table) so was this a Unix system?  (*where no partition table was common*)

Comment: no sdb1 showed up. no, it was a dos/windows system. and a very old one, like 1995. and that drive is still booting into dos 6.2x on the old computer.

Comment: still experimenting.   blkid gives dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="xxxxx" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="xxx"

Comment: My earlier comment was asking what OS/release you're using to read the old drive; and we don't provide support for pc/ms-dos 6.2 as this is a Ubuntu Q&A site. I wasn't worried about the old drive, but what you're actually trying to read it on (*I still have systems here running PC-DOS 5.02 & MFM-RLL or later called IDE drives though hardware that old won't run a modern Ubuntu.. but they won't have an ESP (EFI System Partition) so data is being read incorrectly I bet.

Comment: I am on topic as I am also trying to use Ubuntu systems to read the drive. (actually I am trying most of all to use Clonezilla to back it up.  ).  you have given me a good hint there though, and what I suspected. too old a drive will not be recognised by Ubuntu. what I ought to do is to boot up again into DOS 6.2x and see what info I can get about the drive.

Comment: What Ubuntu system is what I've asked (twice!) - the importance being the age of the *software* stack.. as I've had no issues with older Ubuntu product/releases (using 40pin PATA drives), but I've not really attempted on more recent releases as I've had no need.  The *kernel* stack is what I'm asking about; as I've usually used older/GA stacks for accessing older drives, but you've provided no release details; so I can't know what kernel stack you've got available or are using  (as newer Linux kernels add features for newer hardware, don't forget capacity for older hardware gets removed!)

Comment: repeating, I am trying to access a disk/partition with Ubuntu. that is on topic. Ubuntu 22.04.1 and an older Ubuntu on another computer. but stay tuned, some tips here I can try. https://superuser.com/questions/878591/having-issues-mounting-an-old-dos-hard-drive-from-a-mid-90s-486-machine-on-linux sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdxx /media/path/to/mount  is given (though not stating if that can be done on a disk, not partition)also on a disk  ddrescue /dev/sdb hda.img hda.map  then "Then I scanned through the whole disk, trying to mount every 512th byte offset:"