# WD Red 4T giving 3221GB after format

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

After more than a year of use I was shocked discovering that my 4TB WDC_WD40EFAX-68JH4N0 only gave 3221GB worth of free space. Why is the user capacity only 3.22TB? Where are the other 700Gigs of space? Desperately seeking for more free space, can someone explain if the original format maybe was done wrong and how to get more space out of this 4TB drive?

Information about the disk:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdb
print free

Model: ATA QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3221GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:
| Number | Start  | End    | Size   | File system | Name    | Flags |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|-------------|---------|-------|
|        | 17.4kB | 1049kB | 1031kB | Free Space  |         |       |
| 1      | 1049kB | 3221GB | 3221GB | ext4        | primary |       |
|        | 3221GB | 3221GB | 1032kB | Free Space  |         |       |

sudo lshw -C disk
  *-disk:1
       description: ATA Disk
       product: QEMU HARDDISK
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: 2.5+
       serial: QM00007
       size: 3000GiB (3221GB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=daf4d92c-806d-4e8c-be79-64e8f3d629ce logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
```

```
       size: 3000GiB (3221GB)
```

∆ this is what puzzled me. Only 3TB?

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     QEMU HARDDISK
Serial Number:    QM00007
Firmware Version: 2.5+
User Capacity:    3,221,225,472,000 bytes [3.22 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA/ATAPI-7, ATA/ATAPI-5 published, ANSI NCITS 340-2000
Local Time is:    Fri Aug 25 14:13:44 2023 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Comment: Why does it say QEMU hard disk? Are you on a virtual machine? What's the output on the host system? 3000GiB is a *very* round number. *Too* round.

Comment: so is 2199Gb for a 320Mb   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482971/trouble-mounting-a-fat32-ide-drive-with-usb-adapter-thinks-a-520mb-disk-is-2000?noredirect=1#comment2596649_1482971

Comment: @muru You are so right! I thought I was on the host system but that one was also virtualized on Proxmox. I totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

So doing a parted /dev/sda on the actual host system (Proxmox) the model is correct displayed and also its size. Now I can grant more free space to the virtual machine. Thanks!
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print free
Model: ATA WDC WD40EFAX-68J (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

| Number | Start | End | Size | File system | Name | Flags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 17.4kB | 1049kB | 1031kB | Free Space |  |  |
| 1 | 1049kB | 4001GB | 4001GB | ext4 | primary |  |
|  | 4001GB | 4001GB | 860kB | Free Space |  |  |